# Autodesk forge Autodesk.DiffTool problem in "sidebyside" mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to compare two 3d models with Autodesk.DiffTool.
But there are some problem in "viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.DiffTool').setDiffMode('sidebyside')"
Below is the execute result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCkLN.png)
Left side's model didn't show up.

I operate visible button in model browser ,but it can't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUHMO.jpg)

After loading the first document then execute the below code.
There is no error,but left side model still doesn't show up

```
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc2, doc2.getRoot()
    .search({ name: oldVersionName })[0]
    .getDefaultGeometry(),
    { keepCurrentModels: true }).then(m2 => {
        model2 = m2;
        var extensionConfig = {};
        extensionConfig.mimeType = 'application/vnd.autodesk.revit';
        extensionConfig.primaryModels = [m1];
        extensionConfig.diffModels = [m2];
        extensionConfig.diffMode = 'sidebyside';
        extensionConfig.versionA = newVersionName || 'New Version';
        extensionConfig.versionB = oldVersionName || 'Old Version';

        viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DiffTool', extensionConfig)
            .then(function (res) {
                window.DIFF_EXT = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.DiffTool');
                console.log("DiffTool has been loaded.")
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });


    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the issue as well. The `overlay` mode seems to be working well, but after switching to the `sidebyside` mode, I see many WebGL errors in the console.

[image]

I will report this issue to the viewer team. As soon as it is resolved, we will report it in the [changelog](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/), so please stay tuned.

EDIT:

While the issue is being addressed, please consider adding `useSplitScreenExtension: true` to the options of the DiffTool extension. With this flag enabled, the feature works as expected.

Comment: Thanks,`useSplitScreenExtension: true` can work!